# IONIC 1 - download pdf in mobile not working:

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jspdf, ionic-native, ionic-v1

I am working on a project based on ionic 1.x .By using 'jsPDF' , I have created a PDF file. The file is downloaded when testing in browser but doesn't work when tested in an android device.

The code is as follows

```js
var doc = new jsPDF()
doc.text(pdfstr, 10, 10)
doc.save('a4.pdf');
```

Thanks

Comment: This might be a CORS issue. Check if your server allows CORS.

Comment: I am deploying this as a mobile app.A browser has capabilities to download a file from a website.The app cannot do such downloads. Also, there are no CORS issues.Thanks for replying.

Comment: I used the cordova file plugin and it worked in android just fine.